# How to pass extra parameters along with New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-group, azure-rm-template

I'm writing a powershell  script to create VM using New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet, which is as below.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name VmDeployment  `
  -TemplateFile C:\template\template.json `
  -TemplateParameterFile C:\template\parameters.json
```

This is used create a VM. In `parameters.json` , there are some parameters like `virtualMachineName`, `networkInterfaceName` etc which are hardcoded.
Now I'm trying to automate these scripts , i.e they run on there own from a tool , when ever some condition is met.

My requirement here is , whenever this script runs, it has to increase the number in the VMName . Suppose the VM Name is now `VMName1`, it has to be `VMName2` when the script runs next time. Similarly `VMName3` when the script runs next time. Since the `virtualMachineName` parameter is hardcoded, this is not happening now. Is there anyway I can pass `virtualMachineName` as a parameter in the script itself rather than taking it from the json file.

Any guidance is highly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can definitely do this, and fortunately there are a handful of ways too.

1. **Pass inline parameters**. It says in the [Azure PowerShell docs for Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy#parameter-files) that you can use inline parameters with a local parameter file and the inline parameters take precedence. Relevant paragraph:

> You can use inline parameters and a local parameter file in the same deployment operation. For example, you can specify some values in the local parameter file and add other values inline during deployment. If you provide values for a parameter in both the local parameter file and inline, the inline value takes precedence.

This is valuable because it provides you explicit control over the VM Name parameter, but it is up to the caller (you in this case) to pass an inline parameter. Please note this only works with **local** parameter files and not remote files (i.e. `-TemplateParameterFile` and not `-TemplateParameterUri`). The resulting command would look something like:

```
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name VmDeployment `
      -TemplateFile C:\template\template.json `
      -TemplateParameterFile C:\template\parameters.json `
      -virtualMachineName VMName42
```

2. **Modify original *parameters.json***. You can write some PowerShell/Python/Favorite-scripting-language to parse *paramters.json*, find the VM Name parameter, find the integer suffix, increment it, and overwrite the file with the new version. This has the benefit of not having to remember to pass an inline parameter, and you won't have to track the version number anywhere as it is already stored in *parameters.json*. This has one major drawback: it modifies the original JSON which can be dangerous.
3. **Copy *parameters.json* and modify temporary copy**. You can write a script to copy *parameters.json* to another temporary JSON file and then increment the VM Name parameter during the copy just like in option 2. Pass this temporary file to `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`. This has the benefit of not modifying the original *parameters.json* file but requires you to track the version number somewhere (e.g. another local file, a command line parameter, environment variables, etc.).

For simplicity, I would recommend option 1. It already works out-of-the-box and does not require any external scripts.

Comment: this is wrong. you can pass in inline parameters with `templateparameteruri`, there is just no intellisense. overall the temporary parameters file is the best approach. inline parameters are useless if you are doing anything serious

Comment: I disagree, and so do the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy#parameter-files): "When you specify a parameter file in the TemplateParameterUri parameter, all inline parameters are ignored."

Comment: I appreciate you disagreeing, but facts dont care about your feelings (c). `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName xxx -TemplateUri 'https://raw.githubusercontent.
com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-vm-simple-windows/azuredeploy.json' -adminusername xxx -adminpassw
ord ( ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText '!Qasde32') -dnsLabelPrefix  xxx`

Comment: @4c74356b41 the example in your comment does not have TemplateParameterUri .

Comment: eh? what? it doesnt so what? @KarloMedallo

Comment: So... your follow up comment does not help your initial claim.

Comment: did you even test it or what @Adam

Comment: @KarloMedallo is pointing out that your example is not applicable; it does not include the `-TemplateParameterUri` parameter therefore inline parameters are not ignored. No, I did not test it; the burden of proof is not on me since you made the counterclaim but have failed to actually prove your claim.